# Do you need a shell program for Proxy Forwarding?

Tags: ssh, xubuntu, socks5

I am trying to set up a secure proxy for my work. [This article](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/12/08/ssh-tunnel-socks-proxy-forwarding-secure-browsing/) suggests using SSH Tunnel + SOCKS Proxy Forwarding. Do I need to have access to a certain shell program on the server? I have `bash`, `tcsh`, and `zsh` available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server does have direct access to the internet ssh is all you need.
Using the example of the linked article just put localhost port 9999 to your browser's proxy settings and everything is fine.
Another option would be to install an HTTP Proxy server and to use ssh only for portforwarding. E.g. that you local port 8080 is forwarded to the server port 8080 on which a http proxy server is listening.